# How to get Parquet file size and number of lines using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have created the parquet file using Spark.

I have need of parquet meta data like file size and number of lines within it. Is there any solution to get this information using Spark library or Java?

Comment: where is the parquet file ? HDFS ?

Comment: @ Shankar Koirala  ...... not HDFS, parquet file at local system directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java File API in scala to get the size as

```
val file = new File("some.parquet")
val fileSize = file.length
```

This returns the size in bytes you can convert as you want.

If you want the count the records you need to load to spark and get the count.
If you want to get the number of lines then

```
val lineCount = io.Source.fromFile("some.parquet").getLines.size
```

Comment: @avinash chavan Did this helped?